# Integration testing DRF

Tags: django, testing, django-rest-framework, integration-testing

I'm using Django with DRF as just an API--it doesn't serve any FE assets of any kind. I know the Django testing suite is built on the Python native `unittest` library and plan on using it for unit testing.

- When it comes to integration testing, is it sufficient or should something like Behave be used?
- If `unittest` is sufficient, should it be used in conjunction with some kind of faker?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to test the API contract, you need:

- to read [the relevant documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/testing/)
- have a way to generate models you need. My advice is to use [factory-boy](https://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html).

This setup will test your urlconfs, views, serializers and to some extent your models, without the need for real server and without the need to mock API responses.